# Protractor: Stop current spec (and then continue with rest of specs)

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, protractor

I am setting up automated tests for a site, and one of my specs is dependent on a previous spec passing.  The first spec will save a preset configuration in the page, and the second spec will delete it.  So I don't want the second spec to run if the first spec failed to save the preset (otherwise it could delete presets I want!).

If the second spec does not run, I want to continue testing the specs after it.  However, simply putting in a guaranteed-to-fail expect statement in the second spec will allow the spec to continue (which means deleting a preset).  I tried fail-fast, but that will quit testing altogether on a fail, which is not what I want.  I also attempted to utilize asynchronous testing with 'done', but that functioned similarly to expect.

Currently I have this solved by attempting to call a function that doesn't exist.  It fails just the current spec, does not continue the current spec, and begins testing the next spec.  However I feel like there should be a cleaner approach to this.  Is there any built-in way of exiting a spec?

Here's my second spec currently.  `origPresets` is a global variable set in the first spec:

```
it('should allow presets to be deleted', function() {
  return MyPageObject.GetNumberOfPresets().then(function(numPresets) {
    if (numPresets === origPresets) {
      FailingThisSpec();
    }
    // rest of spec starts here
```

Comment: Specs should never depend on each other. Your first spec should be a test for the preset configuration. Second spec should contain the preset steps and the delete steps. That way the specs will be self contained. Start each spec from a clean state. To achieve a clean state, use the `afterEach` block for clean-up after each spec.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple flag that you can set when save operation succeeds in your first spec. In your second spec, just check the flag value with an `if` statement and write all your code of second spec inside the `if` statement. If the `if` statement fails then the execution of remaining specs anyway continues.

Comment: @finspin Good point, I should be doing that, and I will be changing my tests.  However, even if I redo the preset steps in the second spec, if they didn't work in the first spec they won't work in the second.  Thus I still need a way to exit the spec if I couldn't create a preset.  Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @girish Ah yeah that would have worked to.  I ended up finding a cleaner way by just `return`ing when I'm in the `if` statement I have coded above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [fail()](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Manually_failing_a_spec_with_%3Ccode%3Efail%3C/code%3E) function in jasmine 2.x should help your problem if i understood you correctly.

```
it('should allow presets to be deleted', function() {
  return MyPageObject.GetNumberOfPresets().then(function(numPresets) {
    if (numPresets === origPresets) {
      fail("Can't delete");
    }
    // rest of spec starts here
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe i couldn't find that.  Thanks!  
It didn't completely solve my issue, because even after the fail() it will continue running the rest of the spec.  However I've been coding in Coffeescript and totally forgot about 'return'... so this followed by return is exactly what I needed!